# Big O notation of a specific method

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What's the Big O notation of the following method and why?

```
public int f(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return f(n/2) + n;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Have a look at the Masters Theorem.